# SCP one-liner to upload file at end of line

Tags: bash, scp

I often do this:

```
scp some_file really@long.server.name.com
```

I'm annoyed by this because I always copy-paste this line, and then I need to edit the middle to change the file I want to upload.

Is it possible to tinker with this line so the file name will be at the end and it'll still work?

Basically I want any string of characters that I can paste into a shell, then type a file name and have it upload the file with `scp` to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

```
(read FILE_NAME; scp "$FILE_NAME" really@long.server.name.com) <<< some_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not make a super-simple script?
Just edit a file named say `myscp` containing

```
#!/bin/bash
scp $1 really@long.server.name.com
```

and then `chmod +x myscp`, so that later you can simply

```
./myscp some_file
```

This is all assuming your `myscp` script is located at the current directory, otherwise add the path

```
/path/to/myscp some_file
```

or better yet, add the path of the location and this and -hopefully- future scripts to your `$path`.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the end of your `.bashrc` or equivalent for your shell:

```
my_function_name() {
    if [ -r "$1" ]; then
        scp "$1" really@long.server.name.com
    else
        echo "File does not exists or can not be read, $1" >&2
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Change `my_function_name` to your needs.

Now you can just invoke the function by name and pass a file as argument and it will be tested for read access and run `scp` with it or quit if can not read it.

Note that I used `return` instead of `exit` because it will be loaded by your interactive shell, and if you use `exit` the shell will terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ssh_config` to shorten your `really@long.server.name.com`. Create a file `~/.ssh/config` with

```
Host alias
  HostName long.server.name.com
  User really
```

and then connect simply using `scp some_file alias`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the order of the parameters without wrapping it in a shell script, but you could...

```
R='really@long.server.name.com'
scp some_file $R
scp other_file $R
...
```