# Connect to my server with a name rather than IP address

Tags: ssh, ip

I have setup a Centos Linux Server. I can connect to my server with command:

```
ssh My_Name @ Ip_Address
```

How can I set a name for my server so that I can connect with the command:

```
ssh My_Name @ My_Server_Name.com
```

The `.com` or '.net' does not matter, I just want to have a name for my server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCP one-liner to upload file at end of line](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313505/scp-one-liner-to-upload-file-at-end-of-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to do this for convenience, the simplest method is to add a stanza to your ssh configuration file `~/.ssh/config` :

```
Host my_server_name
    HostName some_ip_address
    User my_name
    ... any other options
```

Then you can `ssh my_server_name` to connect.

---

Other options include:

- using mDNS and connecting to the `.local` name your machine advertises (mDNS is called `bonjour` in the Apple world; a common linux implementation is `avahi`).
- editing the `/etc/hosts` file on each client machine to provide a mapping from the IP address to the chosen server name.
- installing and configuring a DNS server on a machine in your local network, and setting it as the preferred DNS server for all other local machines.

Comment: My intention is rather something else. when I connect to my server from outside of home I need to use `IP_Address_1` and when I connect inside home [within my home network] I need to use `IP_Address_2`. So I want to set a name, so that I can always use a unique name wether in home or out of home.

Comment: @Admia, if you want a FQDN you can use from inside or outside your house, I think you would need to (1) lease a domain (2) set up outside name resolution per your registrar's instructions and (3) set up a DNS server in your home that would provide local addresses for the same names.   Alternately, you could write a wrapper script which would check your current IP address, and ssh to *either* the local or the public IP for your centos system, depending on whether you were in or out of the house.

Answer (score 2):

And to add a further possibility if you want a more general solution than just for your ssh connection, you could add the alias to your /etc/hosts file

```
IP address              YourAlias1 ...
```

This would allow you to use the alias with any other programs, but wouldn't include the ssh user name as the first answer gave.